# How to display only the records that satisfy the condtion in a gridview using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, records

I am inserting a new record in a form that has two textboxes txtName, txtAge and I am using an ajax calender extender txtDOB and a gridview control gdvDisplayRecords with 3 fields name, dob and age. So when i select any date from ajax calender extender, the gridview must display only those records from the database which have same DOB before i try to add this new record. Please help me with the code as i am new to gridview control.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way would be filtering grid-view data source. For example, if grid-view is bound to a DataTable then you can create DataView with filter on DOB and bound grid to the view. If your data source is an array or list then use methods such as [Array.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd.aspx) or [List.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) for filtering.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Let me try filtering grid-view data source as my grid-view is bound to a Data Table.